# Intelligent Task Scheduler

Tags: scheduled-task, task-scheduler, scheduling

Is anyone aware of a tool for creating optimal schedules for tasks? I have numerous servers, running multiple databases, with various scripts that import and transform data to and from each database.

I'm currently scheduling the various cronjobs by hand, but this is error prone and difficult to account for exceptions, such as a job taking unusually long to run because of an unusually large data load. I'm considering encoding the resources and dependencies between each task, and creating a planner to search for an optimal sequence of task executions so each task is run at a time when it's least likely to interfere with any other tasks.

I've seen [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner), but it's not appropriate due it's immense complexity and overhead.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fair to ask what type of platforms you're concerned about managing. I'm assuming Linux, but the concept applies to Windows systems as well...

You are looking for a [job scheduler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Job_scheduler). It's not an easy thing to get into, but can potentially help scalability and would manage your inter-process dependencies. A good solution to start with is the [Open Source Job Scheduler](http://www.sos-berlin.com/modules/cjaycontent/index.php?id=62&page=osource_scheduler_introduction_en.htm) (commercial solutions are [prohibitively-expensive](http://documents.bmc.com/products/documents/26/76/62676/62676.pdf)).